# Why does my cacluator repeat the same output when I use a decimal value?

Tags: c++, math

I have written this code. It is working good, I am curious though. When I add a decimal number in one of the functions why does the rest of my functions repeat the same code and finish? I know it works when I assign the number input as double. I am curious though why it funtions like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int num1, num2;

int request(){
    cout << "Type in a number: " << flush;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Type in a number: " << flush;
    cin >> num2;
}

int getMin(){
    cout << "Get the minimum of 2 numbers" << endl;
    request();
    if(num1 < num2)
        cout << "The minimumm of " << num1 << " and "
                << num2 << " is " << num1 << endl;
    else
        cout << "The minimumm of " << num1 << " and "
                << num2 << " is " << num2 << endl;
}

int getMax(){
    cout << "Get the maximum of 2 numbers" << endl;
    request();
    if(num1 > num2)
        cout << "The maximum of " << num1 << " and "
                << num2 << " is " << num1 << endl;
    else
        cout << "The maximum of " << num1 << " and "
                << num2 << " is " << num2 << endl;
}

int power(){
    cout << "Get the exponent of 2 numbers" << endl;
    request();
    cout << num1 << " to the power of " << num2 << " is "
         << pow(num1,num2) << endl;
}



int main(){


    getMin();
    cout << endl;
    getMax();
    cout << endl;
    power();
    cout << endl;

}

output
Get the minimum of 2 numbers
Type in a number: 5.5
Type in a number: The minimumm of 5 and 0 is 0

Get the maximum of 2 numbers
Type in a number: Type in a number: The maximum of 5 and 0 is 5

Get the exponent of 2 numbers
Type in a number: Type in a number: 5 to the power of 0 is 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564771

Comment: Your code (in every function) is reading values of type `int`.   When it encounters a `'.'` in input, streaming operators stop, LEAVE the `'.'` in the stream buffer, sets a stream error state, and returns  - all since input for an integral value should NOT contain a `'.'` character.   The next time the streaming operator is called to read an `int`, the same happens.  The result is appearing to run through all subsequent input.    Change the variables to type `float` or `double` if you want input to be non-integral (e.g. like `5.5`).

Comment: @Peter not exactly, reading the first value works, `cin` stops at the `.`, but is not in an error state. It will be in an error state after the second reading: https://ideone.com/Wit2Yi

Answer (score 0):

> why does the rest of my functions repeat the same code and finish?

It's because when the extraction of an `int` fails, the character making the extraction failing is left in the stream (and will be encountered every time you try a new extraction) and the stream is set in a failed state making any further attempts to extract data from the stream failing - so whatever values you've previously set for `num1` and `num2` will be reused over and over. If no value was assigned, you read uninitialized memory and your program has undefined behavior.

To recover from a failed extraction you can `clear()` the stream's state flags and `ignore()` the characters in the stream until end of line.

Also, your `request()` function and the rest of the functions have undefined behavior anyway. They are declared to return an `int` but does not return anything, so make them `void` instead.

You could however change `request()` to return a `bool`. Return `true` if the requrest succeeded and `false` otherwise:

```
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits

bool request() {
    cout << "Type in a number: ";
    if(cin >> num1) {
        cout << "Type in a number: ";
        if(cin >> num2) return true;     // both numbers extracted successfully
    }

    // something failed
    if(not cin.eof()) { // skip clearing the state if eof() is the reason for the failure
        cin.clear();    // clear the fail state

        // ignore rest of line to remove the erroneous input from the stream
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can now use it and make sure that the user actually successfully entered the two values. Example:

```
void getMin() {   // made it void since it doesn't return anything
    cout << "Get the minimum of 2 numbers" << endl;
    if(request()) {               // check that extraction succeeded
        if(num1 < num2)
            cout << "The minimumm of " << num1 << " and "
                 << num2 << " is " << num1 << endl;
        else
            cout << "The minimumm of " << num1 << " and "
                 << num2 << " is " << num2 << endl;
    }
}
```