# C++ Simple Hi-Lo game unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, std

I am trying to learn cpp using learncpp.com. So far, I don't really have any questions about the tutorial series themselves.

After chapter 3, I tried to write my own simple Hi-Lo game in order to test if I understand the basics enough to write a very simple program completely on my own.

I'll put my code files here, and then I'll explain the unexpected behaviour.

Main.cpp:

```
#include "io.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <string>

int main() {
    int x{ getNumberFromConsole() };
    int target{ getRandomInt() };
    
    while (x != target) {
        if (x > target) {
            printToConsole("Lower");
        } else if (x < target) {
            printToConsole("Higher");
        }

        x = getNumberFromConsole();
    }

    printToConsole("Correct, the answer is:");
    printToConsole(std::to_string(target));
    return 0;
}
```

math.h:

```
#ifndef MATH_H
#define MATH_H

int getRandomInt();

#endif
```

math.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int getRandomInt() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNumber{ rand() % 100 };
    return randomNumber;
}
```

io.h:

```
#ifndef IO_H
#define IO_H
#include <string>

int getNumberFromConsole();
void printToConsole(std::string x);

#endif
```

io.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int getNumberFromConsole() {

    int x{};
    std::cout << "Type a number: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}

void printToConsole(std::string x) {
    
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

The compiler I currently have configured is the following (if this matters at all):

```
PS C:\Users\ADMIN_VM\Documents\C++\helloworld\hi-lo-attempt\output> g++ --version

g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Now for the unexpected behaviour: when I run the "game" and just enter integers into the terminal as I should, the game works as expected from start to finish.

The issue is: when I enter a string (charachter). For example: "K". I expected that the "game" would treat the letter K as an integer with value 0. This is also confirmed by the debugger when I enter the letter "K": x has a value of 0.

The quiz part of this page of the tutorial series also states that when a character such as H is entered, the value of the integer will be 0: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-iostream-cout-cin-and-endl/

What actually happens is the game states "Higher" (as expected, 0 is probably lower than the target), but instead of allowing the user to enter another value, the game gets stuck in a loop and keeps printing `Type a number: Higher`

I don't really understand why this happens. I would've thought that either my program would crash, or it would just ask for a new number and treat the character as a 0.

In testing I concluded that the only explanation I could think of is that my function `getNumberFromConsole()` somehow takes the output from the previously called function `printToConsole(std::string x)`, but that doesn't seem logical to me.

Can someone explain to me what exactly is happening here, and why it is doing this?

I know the header files and multiple cpp files are probably more than overkill for a trivial program like this one, but I wanted to train everything I have learned so far.

I don't really understand what causes this behaviour and I am very interested in knowing what causes it.

Comment: *I expected that the "game" would treat the letter K as an integer with value 0* -- Is that all?  [Maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564771/cin-condition-checking-error).  You try to fool the stream by entering something invalid, it doesn't go unnoticed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if I understand correctly, if the `std::cin >> x` in my code gets another input than an integer, it errors out, ignoring any further input. I still don't understand how that puts my code in an infinite loop. Does the `std::cin >> x` repeat forever? Or is there something else happening that I fail to see?

Comment: Before doing anything else, have you verified that your loop actually works when given valid input?  If not, then the issue is not the input, it's your `while` loop and the logic.  And if it's because the input is 0, then have you actually entered 0 to see if your observations are correct, and not `K` to mess things up with the stream?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the game plays normally if all that is ever entered are integers. When just a 0 is entered, or any negative integer, the game also behaves normally. When invalied input is given, such as a float or a string, I get stuck in the loop. I will try to study the `std::cin` behaviour and handling a bit more, as it seems to indeed have to do with `std::cin >> x`. I was confused at first because the debugger gave a valid value for x when entering str or float (0 if str, dropping the decimals if float). But now that I know that `std::cin` has an error state, I can seek further.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I never use something like cin >> someInt. I always do my own parsing so I can do my own error handling. So instead I would do input as:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
```

And then I write methods that verify line contains (in this case) only digits. Then you have the ability to report errors however you want and all the other control you need.

Here's another issue in your code:

```
int getRandomInt() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNumber{ rand() % 100 };
    return randomNumber;
}
```

You want the srand() call ONLY ONCE. Move that into your main() before any calls to getRandomInt(). What you are doing is re-seeding the random number generator over and over. You don't want to do that. Just do it once.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I have posted another answer which still does not completely solve the issue, but It already clarified a lot when I researched the comment PaulMcKenzie posted.

About the `srand` function: is there a particular reason you don't want to change the seed every time? `getRandomInt()` is always called only once when this program is ran.

I would think that in a use case where good "randomness" is required this would even be better, as new seeds also mean other psuedo-random numbers? Or does this increase the chance of collisions?

Comment: You could just as easily take the current time, turn it into milliseconds, and then modulo 100 if you're going to reseed each time. As you're only calling it once, it doesn't matter, but the accepted way is to only seed once. Note that only seeding once gives you the option of seeding with a *specific* value so that you can duplicate the results from a previous run.

Comment: I see. The problem here is that calling the srand in my main function will require me to include both `cstdlib` and `ctime` in my main function, which I'd rather avoid for now. Is there any way to call srand only once, and also NOT have it in the main? I guess making a function like `useSeed()` or something similar and only using that once would be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I have found what caused this unexpected behaviour for me. I was looking at the wrong place at first.

The value of X actually is not the problem here, the problem is inside my `getNumberFromConsole()` function. I will paste the contents of my **first** io.cpp file here again for convenience.

io.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int getNumberFromConsole() {

    int x{};
    std::cout << "Type a number: ";
    std::cin >> x;  // This line causes the issue

    return x;
}

void printToConsole(std::string x) {
    
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

After reading the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564771/cin-condition-checking-error) in the comment posted by @PaulMcKenzie, I learned that the `std::cin` does not simply ignore wrong input and wait for new input when it is called again. It goes in some sort of "error occured" state.

What actually was happening (if I understand correctly) when I entered the value "h", the line `std::cin >> x` could not be satisfied: h is not an integer, so cin entered an "error occured" state.

It ignores any new input and "freezes" the input stream, so every time my loop ran again, the function `getNumberFromConsole()` would not allow the user to enter a new value. Instead, `std::cin >> x` would read the last entry from the frozen stream again (in this case "h"), which in turn kept the "error occured" state active.

The way to fix this is to first "clear" cin, this removes the errorstate and allows you to work with it input stream again. clearing cin with `std::cin.clear()` itself is not enough however. The "bad" entry (h) is still in this stream and would be read and cause an error in the next iteration of the while loop.

To circumvent this, you could use `std::cin.ignore(x)` where x represents the amount of input charachters to be ignored. The issue here is that, although it will drop the 'h' in this case, this is not a good fix.

If the user would, for example, enter "This is not an integer", you would have to adapt the value of the ignore function to the length of that entered string.

The fix I used here is:

```
if (std::cin.fail()) {  // Check if the input stream is in an error state
    std::cin.clear();  // if so, unfreeze the stream
    std::cin.sync();  // "sync" the stream to ignore any earlier input, waiting for new input to be given.
}
```

This allows for the loop to be repeated without being stuck on the previously entered charachter(s).

The new io.cpp is now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int getNumberFromConsole() {

    int x{};
    std::cout << "Type a number: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.sync();
    }

    return x;
}

void printToConsole(std::string x) {
    
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

It is important to note that the value of X will still be treated as if it is 0 using this method when a string is entered.

P.S.: After some more testing, I noticed that this method does work as expected for strings, but it still makes the loop "error" twice when a float is entered. This still confuses me.

**[EDIT]**: I figured it out: if you enter `2.33`, the number `2` fits in the int x, the part after the decimal point is held in the buffer and the iteration continues.

On the next iteration: cin check the stream and sees there now is only `.33`, which will not fit in INT. Error. Now all of the above applies.

I have tested my program with the debugger for a good hour now, and this seems to be the only reasonable explanation. My best guess is that this behaviour will be diffrent for other compilers or OS'es, depending on how the stream is handled.